# How Login page is working in Jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a login page, i got the jquery code Can anybody explain me this CODE!??
Line by line! so that i know how the hell it is working! i have the code but i dont know how its work.. i am not that good in service integration and stuff

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {

            $('#output').html('Connecting....');

            var postTo = 'login.php';

            $.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() , password: $('[name=password]').val()} , `

                function(data) {



                    if(data.message) {

                        $('#output').html(data.message);

                    } else {

                        $('#output').html('Could not connect');

                    }



                },'json');



            return false;

        });

    });
```

`
In my html :

```
<!-- Start of first page -->
```

```
<div data-role="header">

    <h1>Foo</h1>

</div><!-- /header -->



<div data-role="content">   



    <p id="output"></p>

    <p>

        <form method="post" id="loginForm">

            Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br /><br />

            Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Login">

        </form>

    </p>



</div><!-- /content -->



<div data-role="footer">

    <h4>Page Footer</h4>

</div><!-- /header -->
```

I basically wanna know what $.post is doing? and how?

Comment: Did you already read the [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Comment: check the headers in firebug or chrome's network tab to see the datas being sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post posts a request to a URL with optional parameters and returns a response.

Let's go through your example.

```
$.post(postTo,......
```

The first parameter is the URL to which you are posting the request. This is stored in the postTo variable. In this case it has been set to login.php.

```
$.post(postTo,{username: $('[name=username]').val() , password: $('[name=password]').val()},......
```

The next part contains the data you are passing to this script. You are passing values for "username" and "password" which are being retrieved from the value of an element with the name "username" *$('[name=username]')* and an element with the name "password" *$(name=password)* which in this case are your inputs for username and password.

A successful response from login.php will trigger the callback function. Any data returned will also be available to your function(*data*). This data can be JSON, XML or a string

It works the same as a standard form (except for the callback).

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In the above code, the whole page will redirect to login.php where you would capture the username and password and process it to perform some action. With $.post, you do the same thing without actually redirecting the page. In your login.php script, you capture the posted username and password and return a value.

For instance, you could take the username and password, query your database and if you find a match return "success" or if it does not match you could return "failure". In your ..function(data).. you check to see if the returned value is "success" and perform an action otherwise you perform another action